# How to host Angular 6 application in Python Django?

Tags: django, angular6

I am wanting to host an Angular 6 application in Django, how do I do this?

Comment: This was added as I could not find the answer easily. Hopefully my answer will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumption: That django site is already running

**Things needed to set up Angular 6 locally**

1. Install Node Js.

   > https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Install Angular cli Globally

   > npm install -g @angular/cli
3. Navigate to angular on the repo

   > dir\angular
4. Install the npm's [libraries]

   > npm install
5. Serve the site

   > npm serve [-o]
6. Navigate to the hosted site

   > http://localhost:4200/

**Angular Libraries needed to support Django**

> npm install @angular-devkit/custom-webpack --save
>
> npm install @angular-builders/custom-webpack --save
>
> npm install webpack-bundle-tracker --save

**Django Libraries needed to support Angular**

> pip install django-webpack-loader

**File Architecture - I put my angular project within the djangodir off root**

root > djangodir > angular

root > djangodir > static

root > djangodir > templates

root > djangodir > webpack-stats-angular.json

**Set Up Angular for Django**

1) Alter angular.json to include custom webpack config and change build type to builder

```
 "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js"
          },
        "outputPath": "../static/angular",
```

2) extra-webpack.config.js code

```
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
    plugins:[
        new BundleTracker({filename: '../webpack-stats-angular.json'})
    ],
    output: {
        path: require('path').resolve('../static/angular'),
        filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
    }
};
```

**Set Up Django for Angular**

1) settings.py - added webpack_loader to installed_apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'webpack_loader'
]
```

2) settings.py - added webpack_loader

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {    
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'angular/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats-angular.json'),
    }
}
```

3) requirements.txt - We have a script that pulls from a text file to include dependencies - to this we add

```
django-webpack-loader==0.6.0
```

4) urls.py - set up the init routing to the hello world angular app

```
from . import views as djangodir_views

urlpatterns = [
   # path('', include(router.urls)),
   path('', djangodir_views.serve_angular, name='serve_angular')
]
```

5) views.py - include url path

```
def serve_angular(request):
    return render(request, 'angular.html')
```

**Angular.html Page:**

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular/TypeScript Hello World Project</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="Angular Hello World Starter">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- <link href="assets/styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
</head>
<body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-inner navbar-fixed-top">
        <nav class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <span class="app-title"></span>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main class="container">
        <app-root>
            Loading...
        </app-root>
        <br /><br />
    </main>

    <footer>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div class="navbar-inner footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <footer>

                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
{% render_bundle 'runtime' %}
{% render_bundle 'polyfills' %}
{% render_bundle 'styles' %}
{% render_bundle 'vendor' %}
{% render_bundle 'main' %}
</html>
```

**References:**

1. [Angular 6|5 Tutorial: Integrating Angular with Django](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-angular-tutorial/)
2. [Customizing Angular CLI 6 build — an alternative to ng eject](https://codeburst.io/customizing-angular-cli-6-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-a48304cd3b21)
3. [Evolving your Django frontend](https://medium.com/@splatEric/evolving-your-django-frontend-53c7dec5931b)
4. [Angular Hello World Example used](https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular-HelloWorld)

**Routing:**

In order for angular routing to work, you must

1) app-routing.module.ts - Add the routing to angular

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: TestComponent, data: { title: 'Home' }},
  { path: 'test', component: Test2Component, data: { title: 'Test' }}  
];
```

2) urls.py - Add the routing to Django - just point it to the same view

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', djangodir_views.serve_angular, name='serve_angular'),
    path('test', djangodir_views.serve_angular, name='serve_angular')
]
```

Comment: I did excatly that you posted. And I can see only "Loading..." in browser? Should I setup routes for it?

Comment: repeated all steps as prescribed, same result as above,

Comment: @shlomoa same result as dolidod?

Comment: @DolidodTeethtard Yes routes are needed.

Comment: Yes @Demodave , I actually ended up with significantly simpler solution, see my answer beloew

Comment: whole page refresh will occur whenever url changes, how to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

## Integrating **Angular 8** and **django 2.2**

Used Visual Studio for [Django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/install/) and Visual Studio Code for [Angular 8](https://angular.io/cli)

I tweaked the above solution and it ultimately worked. devised a simpler solution using some additional references (listed at the end) on top of the above solution.

Assuming:

- angular is setup at: example/angular
- django  is setup at: example/django

### Distribute angular files directly to django static folder

This is #1 key, the rest is glue (somewhat ugly) code to stitch the frameworks together as painless as possible.

At the console:

> cd example/angular
>
> ng build --prod --output-path ..\django\mysite\mysite\app\static\angular --output-hashing none --watch

Check [Angular/CLI](https://angular.io/cli) for command line switches and their use, the key here that the output of angular compilation goes directly to Django, no need for a middle man.

### Maintain independent FE and BE for development and testing

**Note:** this is optional, you could "ruin" your angular development environment and put all django tags and attributes directly in angular, at the cost of losing FE - BE independence.

The index.html distributed in angular cannot be used "as is" in Django.

Here is such an example call it angular.html:

```html
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>mysite</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'angular/favicon.ico' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'angular/styles.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="{% static 'angular/runtime.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'angular/polyfills-es5.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'angular/polyfills.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'angular/main.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** using only Django native language

Serve it in django like any other html

### What else

- Two way routing between django and angular
- Sharing packages like bootstrap
- Strongly recommend [django-rest-frame-work](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) as a starting point
- [BUILDING A WEB APP WITH ANGULAR, DJANGO AND DJANGO REST](https://devarea.com/building-a-web-app-with-angular-django-and-django-rest/) a more complex example putting it all together, I would keep the above simplified django and angular gluing mechanism.

[angular8](/questions/tagged/angular8) [django](/questions/tagged/django)

Comment: Post your solution.

Comment: Brilliant Solution. Cheers.

Comment: Thank You, this helped.
Additional Clarification. The html files should go under the templates/angular folder while putting the remaining under angular/static. That is how mine was setup to serve templates.